# Identify same amounts over different users

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Consider the following table `Orders`:

```
OrderID  Name    Amount
-----------------------
 1       A          100
 2       A            5
 3       B           32
 4       C         4000
 5       D          701
 6       E           32
 7       F          200
 8       G          100
 9       H           12
10       I           17
11       J          100
12       J          100
13       J           11
14       A            5
```

I need to identify, for each unique 'Amount', if there are 2 or more users that have ordered that exact amount, and then list the details of those orders. So the desired output would be:

```
OrderID  Name  Amount
---------------------
 1       A        100
 8       G        100
11       J        100
12       J        100
 3       B         32
 6       E         32
```

- please note that user `A` has ordered 2 x an order of `5` (order `2` and `14`) but this shouldn't be in the output as it is within the same user. Only if another user would have made a order of `5`, it should be in the output.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2):

I would just use `exists`:

```
select o.*
from orders o
where exists (select 1
              from orders o2
              where o2.amount = o.amount and o2.name <> o.name
             );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do :

```
select t.*
from table t
where exists (select 1 from table t1 where t1.amount = t.amount and t1.name <> t.name);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want only selected field then

```
    SELECT Amount,name,
     count(*) AS c
    FROM TABLE
    GROUP BY Amount, name
    HAVING c > 1
    ORDER BY c DESC
```

if you want full row

```
select * from table where Amount in (
  select Amount, name from table
  group by Amount, name having count(*) > 1)
```